# Can't execute a simple HQL query from Hibernate Tools

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, mysql5

I am encountering the following error when trying to execute a simple HQL query (from Famille) from the HQL Editor (hibernate Tools) in Eclipse (Juno):

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.famille famille0_' at line 1
```

here is the detailed error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.famille famille0_' at line 1
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:100)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at $Proxy29.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1978)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate4_0.HQLQueryPage.getList(HQLQueryPage.java:58)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer$ContentProviderImpl.getElements(QueryPageViewer.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1010)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:703)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTableViewer.java:1087)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:917)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getSortedChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1067)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:701)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer$2.run(AbstractTableViewer.java:592)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:590)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createTable(QueryPageViewer.java:225)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.createControl(QueryPageViewer.java:203)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageViewer.<init>(QueryPageViewer.java:160)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView.rebuild(QueryPageTabView.java:109)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.contentsChanged(QueryPageTabView.java:75)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.QueryPageTabView$1.intervalAdded(QueryPageTabView.java:85)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalAdded(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.console.QueryPageModel.add(QueryPageModel.java:67)
at org.hibernate.console.KnownConfigurations$1.queryPageCreated(KnownConfigurations.java:88)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.fireQueryPageCreated(ConsoleConfiguration.java:332)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.executeHQLQuery(ConsoleConfiguration.java:301)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.hqleditor.HQLEditor.executeQuery(HQLEditor.java:447)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.execute(ExecuteQueryAction.java:88)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.run(ExecuteQueryAction.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.runWithEvent(ExecuteQueryAction.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.famille famille0_' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
... 75 more
```

**EDIT:**

Famille.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25 mars 2013 11:54:17 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="beans.Famille" table="famille" catalog="bd">
    <id name="familleId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="familleID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="libelle" type="string">
        <column name="libelle" not-null="true" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="articles" table="article" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="familleID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="beans.Article" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

the generated SQL query:

```
0: beans.Famille
-----------------
select
  famille0_.familleID as familleID103_,
  famille0_.libelle as libelle103_ 
 from
  bd.bd.famille famille0_
```

I am using Hibernate 4 with the MySQL 5 (InnoDB) dialect,

please what I am missing?

Comment: Will you please edit in the relevant entity mappings and the HQL query you're trying to execute?

Comment: hi, to be honest, your question is bad, though so many guys want to help you, but you didn't tell us anything.

Comment: @Alexey trying any query give me an error, I mention: from Town

Comment: @XaviLópez I edited my question, for the query it's: from Town

Comment: @OQJF I didn't give too much details because the mapping works correctly in my application, I encountered this problem only in HQL Editor in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I generated the domain code and the hbm files from my database using Hibernate Tools, the catalog property was set for all my mapping files, so when I execute a query the generated SQL looks for bd.bd.table instead of bd.table.

So I removed the catalog property from all my mapping files

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="beans.Famille" table="famille">
//...
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and now the generated code looks like this:

HQL:

```
from Famille
```

SQL:

```
select
  famille0_.familleID as familleID128_,
  famille0_.libelle as libelle128_ 
 from
  bd.famille famille0_
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query is simply `from Town`, and you get this exception, it means that the mapping of your entity doesn't match the column names in your database.

We could only help more if you gave us the code of the entity and its mapping, the database table definition, and the generated SQL query.

Comment: I did a reverse engineering with Hibernate Tools (version 4) with the MySQL5 (innodb) as Dialect and I just checked my hbm file and the corresponding table, they looks good

Comment: there is an access to a column .famille in the error message. There is no famille column in your mapping. Why don't you do what you're being asked if you want help? Show the code of the entity, its mapping, and the generated SQL query.

Comment: how can I get the generated SQL query ?

Comment: In the "Hibernate Dynamic SQL Preview" tab in eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. I added the generated sql query

Comment: something wrong with this, my database is named bd, I the query is referring to bd.bd.famille instead of bd.famille

Comment: maybe because I set hibernate.connection.url to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3366/bd instead of jdbc:mysql://localhost:3366/